# How do I get the min non-zero value inside this nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this nested dictionary:

```
+-------------+--------------+-------------------+
|    PAK ID   | License used | License available |
+-------------+--------------+-------------------+
| ASG6C1TU08I |      15      |        235        |
| HK5JQ5TFR8Z |      50      |         0         |
| 4HIZBOYUS9S |      81      |        169        |
| 4T6Y77AK1LZ |      50      |         0         |
| X2ACDW29EEH |      50      |         0         |
| W487IEVM0BD |      50      |         0         |
+-------------+--------------+-------------------+

>>> print(license_dic)
{'entry1': {'pak_id': 'ASG6C1TU08I', 'used_license': '15', 'available_license': '235'}, 'entry3': {'pak_id': 'HK5JQ5TFR8Z', 'used_license': '50', 'available_license': '0'}, 'entry5': {'pak_id': '4HIZBOYUS9S', 'used_license': '81', 'available_license': '169'}, 'entry7': {'pak_id': '4T6Y77AK1LZ', 'used_license': '50', 'available_license': '0'}, 'entry9': {'pak_id': 'X2ACDW29EEH', 'used_license': '50', 'available_license': '0'}, 'entry11': {'pak_id': 'W487IEVM0BD', 'used_license': '50', 'available_license': '0'}}
```

I can get the key for the maximum value of 'available license' using this:

```
for k,v in license_dic.items():
    max_entry =max(license_dic, key=lambda v: license_dic[v]['available_license'])
```

Which returns:

```
>>entry1
```

I am trying to get the key for the minimum non-zero value of 'available_license', in this case, it should return 'entry5', because 'entry5 has the lowest non-zero 'available_license'.

I tried:

```
for k,v in license_dic.items():
     min_entry =min(license_dic, key=lambda v: license_dic[v]['available_license'] if key !=0)
```

But I am getting a syntax error

Comment: You need `else` part, right?

Comment: Don't need a for in loop at your first code, the second line is the only thing you need, you can't see you never use the k and v of the loop

Answer (score 0):

1. You absolutly need NO loop, the single `max/min` statement is useful.
2. You are comparing `str` type, you need to parse them as `int`
3. You need an `else` in your test, like use `10**10` (10 billions) as default value to replace the 0, for that you could use an ugly `if/else` (see at the end) or use a boolean way with a `or`

Finally you need

```
max_entry = max(license_dic, key=lambda k: int(license_dic[k]['available_license']))
# entry1

min_entry = min(license_dic,key=lambda k:int(license_dic[k]['available_license']) or 10**10)
# entry5
```

---

Ugly way

```
min_entry = min(license_dic, key=lambda k: int(license_dic[k]['available_license']) if int(license_dic[k]['available_license']) != 0 else 10 ** 10)
```

Comment: Thank you!
It worked... Could you explain the <or 10**10>, I am not understanding it.

Comment: @Checksum321 I use `bool(0) == False`, so if you have 0 it’s like false so it’ll check the value of the other side of the ˋor` which is here 10 pow 10